# Application's onCreate method when android kill the process

Tags: android

I know Application's onCreate is called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created. But what happends when android kills/restart the process, Application's onCreate is always invoked too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it kills/restarts the entire app, yes it should be.  If it just kills your activity, then no it won't.

Answer (score 0):

Once it's killed/restarted, then it will always invoke `onCreate()` method.

Life Cycle of Android can be seen [here](http://studio-developers-android.blogspot.com/2015/03/what-is-android-activity-life-cycle.html).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your Application Runs first time your or if the process of the entire Application is killed than onCreate() method of Application is called else if there are any configuration changes then only  Activity's lifecycle i.e. onCreate(),OnStart()..etc methods will be called.

Generally App's onCreate() method will be invoked only once